# Uploading large file (more than 100 mb) from iPhone to server

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6, asihttprequest

I want to upload large file from iPhone to .net server.
What API I should use?
Also I need to get estimated time for uploading.

How to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

use `AFNetworking` 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking libray for your requirement